# redisplaying an echo and variable will mess up my table?

Tags: php, mysql, database

What I want is the    `echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";` to appear above the table rather than below the table. If I do this though the problem is that it won't calculate the average as the echo is above the variable. But if I move the variable and with it the while loop above the whole table (I need the while loop to select the `$row[Mark]'` field from a query as that is the field that is going to be averaged), it messes up the structure of the table. How can I display the `$average, $total, $count` etc variables and  `echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";` above the table without messing up the table structure?

I tried `$("#record").html(<?php echo "Average Mark: $average"; ?>);` but I get this error on this line:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in /web/stud/u0867587/Mobile_app/exam_grade_report.php on line 135

Below is current code and you can see the `$count++; , $total += $row['Mark'];` in the while loop and the $average variable and echo at the bottom.

```
    <?php

        $result = mysql_query($query);
        mysql_close();

       $("#record").html(<?php echo "Average Mark: $average"; ?>);
     ?>
<div id="record">
    <table border='1'>
          <tr>
          <th>Session ID</th>
          <th>TeacherUsername</th>
          <th>Teacher Name</th>
          <th>Module Number</th>
          <th>Module Name</th>
          <th>Course ID</th>
          <th>Course Name</th>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Student Username</th>
          <th>Student Name</th>
          <th>Mark</th>
          <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
          <?php
           $total = 0;
            $count = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count++;
              $total += $row['Mark'];
              echo "
          <tr>
          <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['TeacherUsername']}</td>
          <td>{$row['TeacherForename']} {$row['TeacherSurname']}</td>
          <td>{$row['ModuleId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['ModuleName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['CourseId']}</td>
          <td>{$row['CourseName']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Year']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentUsername']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentForename']} {$row['StudentSurname']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Mark']}</td>
          <td>{$row['Grade']}</td>
          </tr>";
            }
            ?>

            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
        $average = (int)($total/$count);
        echo "<p>Average Mark: $average</p>";
      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are mixing `javascript` with `php`:

```
<?php

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close();

   $("#record").html(<?php echo "Average Mark: $average"; ?>); // what is this??
 ?>
```

Comment: Somebody told me to try this, don't know what it means

Answer (score 0):

If you just put the stuff you want inside the `<table>` (or any `<tr>`), but outside any `<td>` cells, it will appear above the table.

Comment: I don't think that W3C validators would like that solution.

Comment: True. Okay, I'll add a better answer :p

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define the table headers at the bottom of the table. Something like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>row1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Average: 20</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer, because I've had a better idea to my old one.

Before outputting the table, put:

```
<?php ob_start(create_function('$a','global $average; return "Average Mark: ".$average.$a;)); ?>
```

And after the table is done and you have your `$average` variable defined:

```
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```